# google_maps_flutter sdk probvlem

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, google-maps-flutter

[this error is showing when I want to use googl_maps_flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5R5k.png)

Hello flutter community I'm new to flutter and facing this error:-
I used every thing including flutter upgrade, flutter upgrade --force then also I'm facing this error please help me out

Comment: Please update your dart version

Answer (score 0):

### Follow up the steps:

```
flutter channel stable

flutter upgrade
```

Then Try running the app again.

If the same error occurs, then just go to your ***pubspec.yaml*** file: try changing this

`google_maps_flutter: ^2.1.1` to this `google_maps_flutter: 2.1.1`

---

The caret sign `(^)` is used for [pub dependencies](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies) in Dart to indicate a range of version numbers are allowed.

- E.g. `^2.1.2` is the same as `'>= 2.1.1 < 3.0.0'`.